# How to set a personalized Resource File to BotBuilder-Location?

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I am using BotBuilder-Location dll in Microsoft Bot Framework. I noticed that this dll has a String.resx in Resources Folder with automatics answers/questions.
I want to replace it with a personalized file.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BotBuilder-Location provides a [LocationResourceManager](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/blob/master/CSharp/BotBuilderLocation/LocationResourceManager.cs) class, which is in charge of providing the `strings` that the control uses.

The good news is that all the properties are `virtual` and so you can just inherit from that class in your project, override those properties you want to modify and that's it. You can even create your own resource file in your project and make the overridden properties to retrieve the values from there.

Comment: I create my resource file in my project and it works OK. But I was asking if I can replace the resource file when I initialize the LocationResourceManager. Do you understand me?

Comment: I don't think that is possible since the constructor doesn't receive any parameters, and the one that allows you to specify a resource assembly and a resource name is just internal (https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/blob/master/CSharp/BotBuilderLocation/LocationResourceManager.cs#L256). While providing the assembly will be easier, is still possible to provide your own methods by doing what I explained in the answer (e.g https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/ContosoLocationResourceManager.cs)

Comment: Yes, i create my own project and override de properties like you say. It works fine, thanks men

Comment: you create a class or resource file ?? 
I try with this but Fails :( , can you share u example ?? 
public class FRLocation : LocationResourceManager
    {
        public new string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    }